# How to calculate Joystick margins/thresholds?

Tags: mathematics, joystick

On a joystick that gives float position values **from -1 to 1** on either of **x and y** axis, how do I implement the math that adds "lower" and "higher" circular margins?

---

For example if lower margin is 25% (0.25 float) of radius, and higher margin is 50% (0.5 float), it might look like this:

[image]

The actual "hot" zone is green,  meaning:

1. **Grey** area should always give **0,0** readings of x/y.
2. **Green** area should give **actual values** of x and y form range **-1 to 1**.
3. **Blue** should always give **1** or **-1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing it if you represent the thumb-stick's position as a vector. It's similar to my other answer except it's using vector math, but at least it takes both the x and y at the same time and not just one by one which doesn't work.

If you say that the thumb-stick is at position x0 and y0, then it's corresponding vector u = [x0, y0]. The length of vector u is the distance from the origin (point 0,0). Now if the length of u is less than the lower margin, 0.25 in your case, you can set it equal the zero vector, u = [0, 0].

If the length of u is higher than the lower margin but smaller than the higher margin, then we can us the mapping [low, high]->[0,1] like in my other answer except here the input is the length of u and the output is the length of v, the output vector. To scale a vector we simply make it unit-length by dividing it by its length, then multiply it by however long we want it to be, in this case the length of v.

In the last case if length of u is higher than the high margin, we want it to have a length of 1. To get u to be of unit length, again we divide u by it's length.

Here is an example function that takes a vector u representing the thumb-stick's position and outputs a vector with your new marginalized x and y values. If you actually do it this way, you'd probably want to calculate the length of u once.

```
vector fromUtoV(vector u) {
    vector v;
    if (u.length < low) {
        v = vector(0, 0);
    } else if (u.length >= low && u.length <= high) {
        v = (u / u.length) * ((u.length - low) / (high - low));
    } else if (u.length > high) {
        v = u / u.length;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Interactive demo: http://ggbtu.be/m2237257

Comment: Great algorithm, altough i've optimized it a bit in my implementation - because `u.length` uses squre root (which is cpu consuming) Im keeping `low` as `low_squared` and comparing "unsquared" `u.length` with `low_squared` (then I do `u.length = sqrt(u.length)` right after first `if` case); secondly in the first `else` there is no need to check `else if (u.length >= low...` as the first `if` eliminates this case.

Comment: Second `if` case might be also changed to `< high` comparison instead of `<= high`, so the third (faster) option would be used more frequent, and the last comparison might be omitted leaving only `else` (without any test).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: On afterthought this answer doesn't work when considering both the x and y at the same time. If the thumb-stick was a lever with only 1 dimension of motion, and r was the distance from the center (lever pointing straight up) this should work. So I'm leaving this answer here. I've also have made another answer that's working with a proper 2D thumb-stick.**

How I would solve it would be to map the possible radius values to a corresponding desired value and clamp that. So if I have the radius values r=[0.25, 0.50] and the output values v=[0, 1]. I can find a math function that linearly maps r->v. v is either the x-value or y-value depending on whether the r represents the distance from the center along the x-axis or the y-axis.

```
v = 4 * r - 1
v = clamp(v, 0, 1)
```

Where the clamp function can simply be implemented like this if you are not familiar with it.

```
clamp(x, low, high) {
    if (x < low) {
        x = low;
    } else if (x > high) {
        x = high;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Now I assume negative value means the thumb-stick is going in the opposite direction. You never explained whether or not the radius can be negative, if it can't and you can tell the direction through some other means you can use the method above and put on the minus sign at the end if appropriate. If radius does become negative in the other direction, we need another mapping function, this time going from r=[-0.50, -0.25] to v=[-1, 0].

```
v = 4 * r + 1
v = clamp(v, -1, 0)
```

Unfortunately we can't use math expression for both ranges since both 0.25 and -0.25 are suppose to map to 0, the same value. However we can write a program function that combines both of the above for you. This does assume r goes from -1 to 1.

```
float mapRtoV(float r) {
    int v;
    if (r > 0) {
        v = 4 * r - 1
        v = clamp(v, 0, 1)
    } else if (r < 0) {
        v = 4 * r + 1
        v = clamp(v, -1, 0)
    }
    return v;
}
```

If your want values other than 0.25 and 0.50, here is a general function. Where low and high would be low=0.25 and high=0.5.

```
float mapRtoV(float r) {
    int v;
    if (r > 0) {
        v = (x - low) / (high - low)
        v = clamp(v, 0, 1)
    } else if (r < 0) {
        v = (x + high) / (high - low) - 1
        v = clamp(v, -1, 0)
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
in = <2D input vector with [-1;1] value range>
map_min = 0.25;
map_max = 0.5;

l = length( in );
n = l > 0 ? in / l : vec2(0,0); // normalized input vector
// assuming max != min so division by 0 cannot happen
rl = ( l - map_min ) / ( map_max - map_min ); // remapped length
if( rl > 1 ) rl = 1;
if( rl < 0 ) rl = 0;
out = n * rl; // the corrected 2D input vector
```